How to retrieve windows user while sending angular request to .NET Core 8?
I've been struggling too much on this, I have an Angular application with .NET Core 8 and all I want is to get the Windows user from a client request because I need to log who makes certain action.
I have tried too many things and none of them work, I always get isAuthenticated = false.
Here is some of my code, can somebody help me?
Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

launchingSettings.json:
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:2390",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5015",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    }
  }
}

proxy.config.js:
const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
    env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:5015';

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/api/MyApi",
    ],
    target,
    secure: false,
    onProxyRes: proxyRes => {
      const key = "www-authenticate";
      proxyRes.headers[key] = proxyRes.headers[key] &&
        proxyRes.headers[key].split(",");
    }
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;

MyApiController.cs:
public MyApiController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) 
{
    this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}

[HttpGet]
public List<string> GetMyApi()
{
    // Here I need to get the Windows user and I always get isAuthenticated = false
    //...
}

I'm also passing withCredentials = true when calling the API:
this.http.get<string>[]>('/api/MyApi', { withCredentials: true })

This is the info when calling the API, I'm not sure if the authentication is in fact being passed, one thing I noticed is that server says: "Kestrel" and I read that there is no Windows authentication using that, is that true? Would that be the issue? I also tried using IIS Express but then I get 500 error.

Let me know if you need more info, I would also appreciate if you can point me to the right direction, I'm new in .NET Core by the way.

Do you have a builder.Services.AddAuthentication() somewhere? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

That is one of the many things I have tried, I had that line commented actually but I just uncommented it and I tried again but still the same.

Why do you have anonymousAuthentication as true when gunr's link says to have it as false?

I also tried that but sill doesn't work, actually I have read that article before and I tried everything there but nothing work for me.

Could you share your repo without any sensitive information? As you mentioned,  you have tried builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)    .AddNegotiate(); , now you have commented it, but it's needed.

We need to debug it, so that we can know what happened in this issue.

@JasonPan I could finally find a solution but I didn't like it, it should be a better way. I had to make the calls directly to the port where the server is hosted (in this case 5015) using an interceptor from angular side, I created a dummy project from scratch, here is the code, if you want to simulate my problem just remove the interceptor from the providers section in app.module.ts. The request always throws 400 error in this case.
https://github.com/razielx4crazy/TestingAuth

@user6009865 After testing, you will encounter a 400 error later because you accessed https://localhost:4200/weatherforecast, and the port is wrong. If you can use a format like  this.http.get<WeatherForecast[]>('${environment.apiBaseUrl}/weatherforecast' in app.componment.ts, this problem should be solved well.

First of all thank you for taking your time on this! About what you commented, that is actually the solution I found but I added that logic to the interceptor because I would need it to every api call.
What I don't understand though is, why without the AddAuthentication it works fine as it is, I mean, calling the apis using the port 4200?
